# google analytics tracking orders made in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, analytics, tracking

So I have ga.js code tracking orders in my web application. These are then picked up in the Conversions-->Tracking-->Transactions section in Google Analytics. The thing is I'm getting average 80-90% of my orders showing up in GA. I've read up online that it is normal that a small percentage of orders wont show up in GA. Is this a correct assumption to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct because many users block monitoring sites like that one.

The information is given by javascript call, that is also mean that users with javascript disabled, or get javascript error on page, also fail to send that info to google.

The block can be done either using antivirus/anti malware programs, ether direct by add some site names on the host file of the system and changing the IP to localhost so they fail to run. Its an easy trick if you try to avoid some sites that monitor you.

If you wondering if there is a way to always give that infos regarding if the user blocks it, yes there is, you send that informations on code behind direct on google server, but its a little complicate.

And one tip - better keep that infos for your only.